# mysql with Exited(1) from docker

Tags: mysql, docker

Start learning docker and try to setup a mysql container.  But it dies immediately with Exited(1).

Following is the command used

```
docker run mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password1
```

Looking at docker ps, it does not show any running docker container

with docker ps -a  returns the following :

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE   COMMAND                     CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS    NAMES
e681f56c52e2    mysql   "/entrypoint.sh -e MY"      3 seconds ago       Exited(1) 3 seconds ago                  lonely_rosalind
```

Nothing shows up for docker logs lonley_rosalind either

Any idea how to determine why if failed ?

I am running

- ubuntu 15.04
- docker version 1.9.1 build a34a1d5

Comment: You could as well look into logs before asking. `docker logs e681f56c52e2`, in general `docker logs <container_name_or_id>`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password1 mysql
```

When you are writing something after docker image name docker accepts it as a command for execution in your created container. Pattern for docker run:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I wish there is some log messages.