# Mysql docker container exited after start, option `-d` has no effect

Tags: mysql, docker

I have problem with mysql-server container.
Post [mysql with Exited(1) from docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386152/mysql-with-exited1-from-docker) has no solution for me included.
Here my workflow on windows 10.
0. Docker version:
`Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`

1. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE blockchain
ENV MYSQL_USER block
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD blockchain
COPY create_schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_schema.sql
EXPOSE 3306
```

2. Build command:
   `docker build -t mysqlserver .`
3. Run command (option `-d` is used):
   `docker run -ti -p 3306:3306 --name mysqlserver1 -v  C:/Users/user/sandbox/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d --net testnetwork mysqlserver --innodb_use_native_aio=0`
4. But result after start is: `Exited (1) 11 minutes ago`, declared path folder for database is initialized.

Where is my error ?

Thx for help

Comment: what is `docker logs your-container-id` showing?

Comment: `[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.21-1.1.3
[Entrypoint] Initializing database
[Entrypoint] Database initialized
Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
` I think problem is, that folder for database is located on windows.

Comment: Could be, I'm not using windows but maybe this can help you? https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: thx for help, I think my OS is broken, because the same workflow for cuchdb db work fine :-(

Comment: currently I removed `-v ...` option, container work fine, but this is not solution for my problem :-(

Comment: posible solution is docker-compose.yml, here runs all without errors, and stable

Answer (score 0):

For mysql docker container, you need to specify the following parameters in your Dockerfile;

1. MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
2. Initial Database to be created
3. Expose Port from the docker container to the host machine

For instance if you're creating the running mysql docker image using terminal, it could be: sudo docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dev --name testdb -p 3800:3600 -d mysql:8.0.17